# Doctrine 1.2, How to build database on web host?

Tags: php, doctrine-1.2

I have my website ready on the localhost and use doctrine 1.2 for the database, I want to upload the website to a web host to try it so I changed the parameters (Database, User, Password, Host) of the DNS in the `config.php` file, but I don't know how to build it since I used to run this command in the CMD:

`php doctrine build-all-reload`

and I can't use the `exec()` command or it's alternatives on a shared host.

I use PHP in my website.

So how can I build my database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a yml file you can create a php script and run the following to create the db from your yml.

```
$options = array(
'packagesPrefix' => 'Plugin',
'baseClassName'  => 'MyDoctrineRecord',
'suffix' => '.php'
);

Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromYaml('/path/to/yaml', '/path/to/model', $options);
```

In general Doctrine_Core has a few methods to create, drop and insert to db after you have set up the connection. It is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Dump your database on localhost and load it on your webhost using whatever means you have available (phpMyAdmin for example)

Migrations will be worse.

Comment: I thought of the same way you suggested, it worked with me but I needed something more professional, or let's say 'Straight Forward', thanks for your response, hoped to mark it as useful but I have less than 15 reputation.